# How to duplicate records in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been stuck for a good while on this issue now and have made zero progress. I don't even know if it is possible...

I have 1 table:

```
+------+------------+-------+---------+------------+
| Item |    Date    | RUnit | FDHUnit | Difference |
+------+------------+-------+---------+------------+
| A    | 19/04/2016 | 21000 |   20000 |       1000 |
| B    | 20/04/2016 |  2500 |     500 |       2000 |
+------+------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Is it possible to Create a new row in the same table for each of those `items` which will display the `Difference` and perhaps a few other columns?

My desired output would be something like this:

```
+------+------------+-------+---------+------------+
| Item |    Date    | RUnit | FDHUnit | Difference |
+------+------------+-------+---------+------------+
| A    | 19/04/2016 | 21000 | 20000   |            |
| A    | 19/04/2016 | NULL  | NULL    |       1000 |
| B    | 20/04/2016 | 2500  | 500     |            |
| B    | 20/04/2016 | NULL  | NULL    |       2000 |
+------+------------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Reason being is that i would like to show a new column and indicate that it is either `Held directly` or `not held directly`.

Comment: Do a UNION ALL, select RUnit and FDHUnit and null in the first one, and the oppsite in the second select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `union all`:

```
select item, date, ruunit, fdhunit, difference
from t
union all
select item, date, null, null, runit - fdhunit
from t
order by item, (case when runit is not null then 1 else 2 end);
```

The `order by` puts the results in the order that your results suggest.  Without an `order by`, the ordering of the records is indeterminate.

Comment: Yikes - I didn't even once think it would be as simple as a `union` - Here i was trying to join it to itself or use a `CTE`. Sometimes its the simplest thing. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
select * from 
(select item, date, ruunit, fdhunit, '' as difference
from t
union all
select item, date, null as ruunit, null as fdhunit, difference
from t) a
order by item, date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Insert into table :

```
insert into table1 
select item,date,null,null,(Runit-fdhunit) from table1 where (Runit-fdhunit)
```

Normal result : 
    select * from table1 
    union all
    select item,date,null,null,(Runit-fdhunit) from table1 where (Runit-fdhunit) <>0

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace `cast(null as number)` with actual type of the `difference` column

```
select item, date, r.ruunit, r.fdhunit, r.difference
from t
cross apply ( 
   select n=1, ruunit, fdhunit, cast(null as number) difference
   UNION  
   select n=2, null, null, difference ) r
order by item, date, n
```